# load package dataset in testthat

Tags: r, testthat

Is it possible to access to package's datasets in the testing unit of a package?

I mean, the dataset is in

> packagename/data/dataset.Rdata

and the testing unit uses the testthat package. Thus it is located in

> packagename/tests/testthat/test-function1.R

I would like to use the package's dataset to perform some tests. Is it possible to load it? I did not manage to find a way, so maybe it is a bad practice to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the file using function `load` and than use it:

```
load("packagename/data/dataset.Rdata")
```

After this command, you will find the dataset in your R environment.